# Chromium Embeded Framework artifacts on textarea control

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I have integrated CEF v1750 in my application and I have some problem with textarea. My app using OpenGL 2.0 to render views.

Textarea looks like that:

http://s8.postimg.org/uzm3rvd8l/textarea.jpg

http://s22.postimg.org/o287ruwap/textarea1.jpg

As you can see in textarea is some icon, which probably comes from some plugin, but why this icon is in each textarea in my application?

Do you know how to disable this icon?

Comment: Icon is `button_save.png`, coming from a Chromium viewer (I can see it when [viewing a PDF](https://github.com/darwin/chromium-src-chrome-browser/blob/master/resources/pdf/index.html) in Chrome for example). No idea why it's in your textarea. Can you see it also if you load your HTML in Chrome?

Comment: No, I can't see it in Chrome. @Sga, that's right, this icon comes from some pdf viewer. 
I use binary version of CEF, and integrate it by cef_wrapper, so I don't have any access to index.html, which has this button. 

Can I fix this without compiling CEF sources?

Comment: You can try removing the plugin, some info about it in [this thread](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6149)